# Is it possible to have a type alias that can't be converted to the base type?

Tags: c, types

I have a typedef like this for example:

```c
typedef char * cstring;
```

Is it possible to make `cstring` not implicitly convertible to `char *` (for example with attributes), so for example if I have a function like this:

```c
int string_compare( cstring rhs, cstring lhs );
```

I could call it like this:

```c
cstring a = [...], b = [...];
string_compare(a, b);
```

but not like this:

```c
char * a = [...], * b = [...]
string_compare(a, b);
```

I accept all solutions even if not standard (GCC only for example)

Explication of why I want to do this:
I have a hidden struct:

```c
struct s_cstring_int
{
  int length;
  int capacity;
  char data[];
}
```

In my function `string_new` I allocate one and return only the data pointer, so the string can be accessed with operator[]

Comment: OT: hiding pointer types with typedefs is a very bad idea. it mostly adds confusion and there is absolutely no benefit.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added an explanation of why I'm doing this

Comment: Seems that your actual problem is how to design the `string_new` function. You should probably make all of this an opaque type instead and name that one `cstring`. See [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888) Ironically, the very examples I used were taken from such a string class that I had named `cstring` :)

Comment: I know, my struct is opaque, but I still want to be able to access my string without `mystring->data`

Comment: "but I still want to be able to access my string without" The language is what it is. You can't have the cake and eat it. If the programmer thinks its such a terrible chore to write `cstring_get(obj);` instead of `obj.cstring();`, to the point where they consider wild redesigns, the whole program design is already on the brink of collapse. "I don't like typing" was never a valid argument, programming is 100% about typing. Copy/paste ftw.

Comment: I guess that you want `char*` not to be convertible to `cstring`. That you want to allow passing `s_cstring_int::data` to functions expecting `char*` like `strlen` but you don't want arbitrary `char*` to be passed to functions expecting `cstring`.

Comment: @tstanisl yes that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typedef pointers are very confusing. Do not use typedef pointers.

> Is it possible to make cstring not implicitly convertible to char *

Sure, just make it a struct.

```
typdef struct cstring_s {
   char *str;
} cstring;
```

> Is it possible to have a type alias that can't be converted to the base type?

No, a type alias is just that - an alias.

Comment: The first paragraph in this answer is a personal opinion. Readers may ignore it.